# Increase the Jenkins login timeout

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Does anyone know how to increase the the timeout window before Jenkins logs out a user?  I'm looking to raise it to 1 day or so.

I work in and out jenkins all day and we keep getting logged out between running of jobs.  Added to this frustration, the 'stay logged in' checkbox doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What version of Jenkins? There was a Jenkins bug related to login cookies: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16278. Even if it's not applicable to your version, it's worth reading through the troubleshooting comments in that bug. That bug also notes that the default login cookie timeout is 14 days.

Comment: @DaveBacher we're running v1.567 and are definitely not getting 14 days of login :)

Comment: @DaveBacher I tested the remember me with a quick kill of the browser client after being logging in for 10 minutes in chrome and firefox and it works, so I think the logout is being forced and breaking the remember me.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Jenkins uses Jetty, and [Jetty's default timeout is 30 minutes](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/6cabf8452e0e08f395a08916397ab6a7e602ff7c/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml#L326-L328). This is independent of authentication settings -- I use Active Directory but it's still this setting that affects timeouts.

You can override the timeout by passing an argument `--sessionTimeout=<minutes>` to the Jenkins init script, or `-DsessionTimeout=<minutes>` to the .war file. For example:

```
# Set the session timeout to 1 week
$ java -jar jenkins.war --sessionTimeout=10080
```

Alternatively, you can edit Jenkins' `<jenkinsHome>/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/web.xml` and add explicitly set it:

```xml
<session-config>
  <!-- one hour -->
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

According to [Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval--) you can set this to 0 to disable timeouts altogether.

To find out the current value for timeouts, you can use the Groovy console provided in Jenkins:

```py
import org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler;
Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval() / 60
```

On my instance, this shows `Result: 30`.

Comment: Seems like the argument should be `--sessionTimeout=<minutes>` (note the equals sign).

Comment: where is the `WEB-INF` directory?

Comment: @bubakazouba On my Debian system, it's in /var/cache/jenkins/war/. On Windows 7, it's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\

Comment: `<jenkinsHome>/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/`

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding an example of using `-DsessionTimeout`. Is it `java -DsessionTimeout=<minues> -jar jenkins.war`? If so we should add that example and change the wording to not be "to the .war file".

Comment: I wasn't able to get DsessionTimeout working, but did get sessionTimeout working.

Comment: As of Jenkins 2.107.2, setting this value alone is not enough. Please check @jhuffaker comment on this question.

Comment: As @Fholst said, just session-timeout doesn't do it anymore

Answer (score 39):

As of Jenkins version 2.107.2 you'll want to include sessionEviction

For example to keep people logged in for 24 hours and 12 hours of inactivity:

```
--sessionTimeout=1440 --sessionEviction=43200
```

If you don't specify sessionEviction people who close the tab will get logged out after 30 minutes.

See the full description on CloudBees' site: 
[Customizing Jenkins login session timeout](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/best-practices/setting-session-timeout)

Comment: The current `sessionTimeout` can be checked in the groovy console with `Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval() / 60`.  Do you know how to get/set the `sessionEviction` in the groovy console?

Comment: You can confirm the eviction idle time like this:
import org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler;
sess = Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getSession();
printf("sessionTimeout: %d seconds\n", sess.getMaxInactiveInterval());
printf("sessionEviction: %d seconds\n", sess.getSessionHandler().getSessionCache().getEvictionPolicy());

Comment: Thank you! This has been plaguing me for over a year and I had never stumbled upon the `--sessionEviction` argument until now.

Comment: Perfect, that explains why session-timeout doesn't seem to do anything by itself.

Comment: in which file should the this be added?

Answer (score 14):

For Ubuntu:

```
nano /etc/default/jenkins
```

Append to **JENKINS_ARGS** at the end of the file:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --sessionTimeout=1440 --sessionEviction=43200"
```

Comment: Excellent, the only answer I've seen on the topic to also say _where_ those parameters are to be applied.
This can be verified with @kmaehashi's code above.

Comment: This is great. What are the units of time for the session timeout? Seconds? minutes? hours?

Comment: @majorgear `--sessionTimeout` uses minutes (1440/60=24h), and `--sessionEviction` uses seconds (43200/60/60=12h).

Answer (score 12):

As of 1.528 you can use the `--sessionTimeout <minutes>` parameter when starting up jenkins via an init script. If starting the war, pass in `-DsessionTimeout=<minutes>`

**Update for 1.6**

If passing in as an arg use `--sessionTimeout=<minutes>`

Comment: This is my jenkins process. But still it times-out under 10 mins. Whats wrong?

"java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx6144m -Xms2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dhudson.diyChunking=false -DJENKINS_HOME=/export/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=80 --ajp13Port=8009 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 --sessionTimeout=600 -Dorg.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.disabled=true"

Comment: Looks like you are launching the war. Try passing in `-DsessionTimeout=600`

Comment: Seems like the argument to jenkins 1.6 should be `--sessionTimeout=<minutes>` (note the equals sign).

Comment: Yep, you are right. Usage for 1.628 is showing `Usage: java -jar jenkins.war [--option=value] [--option=value]` Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

it also seems possible to set it using groovy console:

```
import org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler;
Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(TIME_IN_SECONDS)
```

But I guess it will only be available for current session

Comment: I used this approach and passed zero into the method to disable session timeouts for my current session.

Comment: This worked great for the current session. Is there a way to change these settings for all sessions using the Groovy console?

Comment: you can put this to init0.groovy script:
import org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler;
session = Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(<time in sec>)
session.getSessionHandler().getSessionCache().setEvictionPolicy(<time in sec>);

Answer (score 7):

On my Linux distro, this setting can be added to /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

```
# Pass arbitrary arguments to Jenkins.
# Full option list: java -jar jenkins.war --help
#
JENKINS_ARGS="--sessionTimeout=480"
```

Subsequently, restart with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

Answer (score 4):

This version of Jenkins 1.567 also has the enable auto refresh option so it somehow keeps refreshing the session and I never get logged out. It works for me...

Answer (score 1):

If jenkins installed as debian package (ie with apt), then
with Ubuntu 20.04 what worked for me overriding service configuration:

```
systemctl edit jenkins
# add user session timeout config
Environment="JENKINS_OPTS=--sessionTimeout=720 --sessionEviction=43200"
```

To see all jenkins OPTS, run command:

```
java -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --help
```

Source:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/

Comment: This works on RHEL 9 as well.  Just make sure to edit the `JENKINS_OPTS` variable and not `JAVA_OPTS`.

Answer (score 0):

If Jenkins is running as a Windows service (`jenkins.exe`), parameters can be edited in `jenkins.xml` in the installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Jenkins 2.2x on Windows Server as a windows service the setting

`--sessionTimeout=1440 --sessionEviction=43200`

can be added here

`<arguments>... -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" ... --sessionTimeout=1440 --sessionEviction=43200</arguments>`

located in file `jenkins.xml` in the Jenkins folder, which for me was:

`C:\Program Files\Jenkins` on Windows Server 2012.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins` on Windows Server 2008 R2

Restart the service for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with this for a couple hours and making sense of everything said here this is what I did to solve the issue:

1. Log as sudo user
2. cd /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/
3. vi web.xml
4. Type "i" to go to insert mode
5. Go down until you find `<Session-Config>` and type as screenshot
6. Hit Esc
7. Type :wd to save your changes
8. sudo systemctl restart jenkins

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Not working on Jenkins 2.332.1. Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on CentOS, web.xml will likely be in /var/lib/jenkins/%C/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/. In web.xml, you can add the session timeout and eviction settings to the session config like so:

```
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>480</session-timeout>
    <session-eviction>12600</session-eviction>
  </session-config>
```

Leaving this here for anyone who struggled to find that file like I did.