# How to set user session time for 24 hours in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I have tried to set user session time in Jenkins for 24 hours but nothing worked.

1. added -DsessionTimeout=1440" in JENKINS_ARGS variable in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
2. Unzipped the war file and edited the web.xml file to add the below line and saved it. Archived the edited extracted file using Java -cvf jenkins.war * and uploaded to jenkins but the restart failed.
       1440

I'm new to java tools. Can you please suggest on how to increase the user session time to 24 hours from default?

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407541/increase-the-jenkins-login-timeout)

Comment: Thanks, I have ran the command shown in the link with 1440 value. Here is the output  INFO: Started w.@4b0d79fc{/,file:/root/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/root/.jenkins/war}
Apr 19, 2017 11:23:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context w.@4b0d79fc{/,file:/root/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/root/.jenkins/war}
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Tried  the below one as well and it didnlt worked.${user.home}/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/web.xml


added this entry
<session-config>
<session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>

Comment: edited the war file in /root/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/war.xml and addedd 1440 session time out value and restarted Jenkins. It working as expected now.Thanks everyone