# Increasing Jenkins logout timer doesn't work

Tags: jenkins

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407541/increase-the-jenkins-login-timeout?newreg=65bedaaac6ed453c8758890c3e25492a) to increase the logout timer of our Jenkins server.

If I run the command below in the script console, it displays the output I'd expect.

> import org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler;
> Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval() / 60
>
> Result: 14400

However, our users are being automatically logged out after about an hour and a half.

This didn't start occurring until we switched to Active Directory for user logins - but none of our other services that use AD have this problem. That's the only recent change I can think of.

Comment: Are you using an Operation Center (cloudbees)?

Comment: No, I am not using an Operation Center.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the linked thread in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50937846/3859568), you also need to set sessionEviction nowadays to keep a user logged in:

> For example to keep people logged in for 24 hours and 12 hours of
>   inactivity:
>
> ```
> --sessionTimeout=1440 --sessionEviction=43200
> ```