# Hudson doesn't keep users signed in. How to fix this?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Our team has a hudson instance. Multiple users use it. However, even though a user checks the 'Keep me signed in' checkbox on the sign-in ("Welcome to Jenkins") page, it still asks at every new launch of that link.

I am the admin of the hudson server. Is there a way I can disable this so that the users who use the hudson instance aren't inconvenienced with logging in everytime once they have selected the 'Keep me signed in' checkbox on the sign-in page?

Answer (score 0):

When we migrated our Jenkins server, users started complaining about a similar issue. It turned out that the default session timeout was low (30 minutes).

1. You can check your default timeout:

```
   import org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler;
   Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval() / 60
```

2. Change the timeout (steps for Ubuntu).
   Edit the file /etc/default/jenkins with the settings below and reboot the machine.

   2.1. Add variable session timeout (in minutes).
   `SESSION_TIMEOUT=660`

   2.2. The new variable should be included in JENKINS_ARGS:
   `JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST --sessionTimeout=$SESSION_TIMEOUT"`

You can see also:
[Increase the Jenkins login timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407541/increase-the-jenkins-login-timeout)

Comment: Could you ellaborate a little extra on "you can check your default timeout:" ?  Is that a java call ? what is that ? is that a standalone scrpt ???
And are those numbers in seconds, I presume ?

Comment: In either way... CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009

I edited my /etc/sysconfig/jenkins and added this to keep us logged in for one day: 

SESSION_TIMEOUT=86400 
JENKINS_ARGS="--sessionTimeout=$SESSION_TIMEOUT"

and restarted jenkins... with 

service jenkins restart